# Using multiselect from Enterprise Portal listpage in ax 2012 x++ code

Tags: sharepoint, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I couldn't really find any conclusion to this on the web.

Got an AX listpage that i use in Enterprise Portal (EP).

i got an action menuitem that calls my class EPDocuGet.

I have tried a lot of different code, but it gives error when i use the `getFirst()` method.

here's an example of my code:

```
CustInvoiceJour = args.multiSelectionContext().getFirst();

        while(CustInvoiceJour)// if record exists
        {
            info(CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId);

            // getting the next marked record form the caller form
            CustInvoiceJour =  args.multiSelectionContext().getnext();
        }
```

if i use `CustInvoiceJour = args.record().data();` it will still get the first record in the multiselect.

here's the stack:

```
object not initialized



(C)\Classes\\getFirst 
(C)\Classes\EPDocuGet\run - line 25 
(C)\Classes\EPDocuGet\runDownload - line 16


Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop

   at Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop.Object.CallWithReturnType(String methodName, Type returnType, Object[] paramList)    
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsObjectAdapter.Call(String methodName, Object param1)
```

Anybody knows how to properly do this...?

Heres the rest of the code:

```
    void run(Args args = null)
 {
    IISResponse       response = new IISResponse();
    CustInvoiceJour    CustInvoiceJour;
    MultiSelectionHelper selection;

 ;
   // Transition to a server function to avoid
   // Security problems


   if (args)
   {
     if (args.record().TableId == tableNum(DocuRef))
     {
       EPDocuGet::runDocument(args.record().data(), response);
     }
     // Begin change
     // Description:
     else if (args.record().TableId == tableNum(CustInvoiceJour))
     {
            CustInvoiceJour = args.multiSelectionContext().getFirst();

            while(CustInvoiceJour)// if record exists
            {

                // getting the next marked record form the caller form
                EPDocuGet::downloadPDF(CustInvoiceJour.invoiceid);
                CustInvoiceJour =  args.multiSelectionContext().getnext();
            }
     }
     else if (args.record().TableId == tableNum(MpasMonthInvoiceJour))
     {
        // if(curUserId() == "admin")//todo: here
        // {
            //info(curUserId());
            if(EPDocuGet::createMonthInvoiceJour(args.record().data()))
                EPDocuGet::downloadMonthInvoiceJour(args.record().data(), response);
            else
                warning("Samlefaktura ikke tilgjengelig");
        // }
        // else
         //   EPDocuGet::downloadMonthInvoiceJour(args.record().data(), response);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post all of your method?

Comment: added all of method code in original post